# Декомпиляция Delphi

Tags: delphi, декомпиляция

Как вытащить исходники из ехе файла делфи, т.е. как достать исходники из скомпилированного файла, возможна ли декомпиляция?

Comment: Код Delphi вы не получите, можно только дизассемблировать и получить некомментированный код на ассемблере.

Comment: нет

Answer (score 1):

DeDe(delphi decompiler) + (IDA(Hex-Rays) в последствии перевести с Си, то что будет декомпилировано)